# Rails, menu using ul li cannot open two records simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following html and rails code:

```
<div class="menu"> 
    <%
      # 0 - owner
      # 1 - admin
      # 2 - member
    members.each do |mem|
        #if mem.num != 0 and status !=2
            if mem.num == 1 then role = "admin" end
            if mem.num == 2 then role = "member" end

    %>

    </br>


        <ul id = "#{mem.str}">                                                           
            <li> <%= link_to mem.str%>
                <ul> 
                    <li><td> <%= check_box_tag "members[]", mem.str %> Rights: <%= select_tag "rights[#{mem.str}]", options_for_select(["admin", "member"],role),  :class => "table_column_width" %></p></td></li>             
                </ul>       
            </li>  
        </ul>
    <br/>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

Menu works pretty fine but if I have more then two members I cannot open a menu for the first member and for the second member simultaneously so that I can see the rights of the first and of the second. As soon as I klick on another member, menu of the first member closes and menu for another opens. I want to have menus opened for all members if I clicked to open it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is built in functionality from the browser. When the field loses *focus* it closes the `select` box. You may be able to use a *JS* plugin such as **select2** and try to prevent some of the default behavior or write your own. You could ultimately change it to be a `ul` with nested `li`'s and then use *jQuery* to manipulate the visibility of the fields, it depends on your needs.